# How can I create a (static const?) instance of a class inside itself (ie. a Color class)?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, static-members

I'm trying to create a class for colors. Something like:

```
class Color
{
public:
  float r, g, b, a;
  Color(float r_, float g_, float b_, float a_);
...
}
```

And for convenience I would like to include instances of the class as part of the class so that I don't need to specify the rgba values for common colors as such:

```
image.setPixel(100, 100, Color::Red);
```

However, I don't know what the correct syntax for this is. I've been searching on Google for a while and I haven't been able to find the term for this method :(. I've seen it done in other libraries before, so I think it's possible. I'm thinking it has to be declared as a static constant, but I'm not sure about this:

```
class Color
{
public:
  static const Color Red;
...
}

const Color::Color Red = Color(255, 0, 0, 255);
```

But I get an

> error saying Color::Color is an invalid type

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Red is the member, it should be:

```
const Color Color::Red = Color(255, 0, 0, 255);
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I spent so much time over such a simple mistake D:. I'm going to go eat a cookie to make myself feel better.

Comment: In addition this line should be in a .cpp file, not the header.

Comment: I prefer not to have the equal sign: `const Color Color::Red(255, 0, 0, 255);`